# NaN error on form submission

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to write a simple JavaScript program that calculates the cost of gas based on some parameters from a form. Upon form submission, I get a NaN error inside of the "calculatedMonthlyCost" div.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
<form>
  Cost of Gas: <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 3.10" name="costOfGas"/>
  <br>
  Vehicle MPG: <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 30" name="vehicleMPG"/>
  <br>
  How many miles do you drive to work (one-way): <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 10" name="numMiles"/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br>
</form>

<div id="calculatedMonthlyCost"></div>

<script>
var calcCost = function  (costOfGas, vehicleMPG, numMiles) {
  var dailyCost = (costOfGas / vehicleMPG) * (numMiles * 2);
  var weeklyCost = dailyCost * 5;
  var monthlyCost = weeklyCost * 4;

  return {
    dailyCost: dailyCost,
    weeklyCost: weeklyCost,
    monthlyCost: monthlyCost
  };
}

var userCostOfGas = document.forms[0].costOfGas.value;
var userMPG = document.forms[0].vehicleMPG.value;
var userNumMiles = document.forms[0].numMiles.value;

document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var costs = calcCost(userCostOfGas, userMPG, userNumMiles);
  var calculatedMonthlyCost = document.getElementById("calculatedMonthlyCost");
  calculatedMonthlyCost.innerHTML = costs.weeklyCost;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your input values are Strings. You need to convert them to Numbers before doing operations with them. For example, you can use the unary plus operator to convert them (eg: `var userCostOfGas = +document.forms[0].costOfGas.value;`) or, a longer version of it could be `var userCostOfGas = parseFloat(document.forms[0].costOfGas.value, 10);`

Comment: You need to use `parseInt`.

Comment: @blex: Slight correction: The `parseInt` function takes a base: `parseInt(str, 10)` but the `parseFloat` function doesn't: `parseFloat(str)`.

Comment: @Guffa Good catch! I always try to remember to add the radix with `parseInt`, so it became a reflex. Can't edit my comment anymore, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting the values on page load (when they were empty). You just need to get the values inside the `onsubmit` event listener, and to convert them to Numbers.

```js
var calcCost = function  (costOfGas, vehicleMPG, numMiles) {
  var dailyCost = (costOfGas / vehicleMPG) * (numMiles * 2);
  var weeklyCost = dailyCost * 5;
  var monthlyCost = weeklyCost * 4;

  return {
    dailyCost: dailyCost,
    weeklyCost: weeklyCost,
    monthlyCost: monthlyCost
  };
}

document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var userCostOfGas = +document.forms[0].costOfGas.value;  // < Move these lines here and
  var userMPG = +document.forms[0].vehicleMPG.value;       // < add a plus sign before them
  var userNumMiles = +document.forms[0].numMiles.value;    // <
  var costs = calcCost(userCostOfGas, userMPG, userNumMiles);
  var calculatedMonthlyCost = document.getElementById("calculatedMonthlyCost");
  calculatedMonthlyCost.innerHTML = costs.weeklyCost;
};
```

```html
<form>
  Cost of Gas: <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 3.10" name="costOfGas"/>
  <br>
  Vehicle MPG: <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 30" name="vehicleMPG"/>
  <br>
  How many miles do you drive to work (one-way): <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 10" name="numMiles"/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br>
</form>

<div id="calculatedMonthlyCost"></div>
```

If you only want 2 decimals, you can change this line:

```
calculatedMonthlyCost.innerHTML = (costs.weeklyCost).toFixed(2);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var calcCost = function  (costOfGas, vehicleMPG, numMiles) {
  var dailyCost = (costOfGas / vehicleMPG) * (numMiles * 2);
  var weeklyCost = dailyCost * 5;
  var monthlyCost = weeklyCost * 4;

  return {
    dailyCost: dailyCost,
    weeklyCost: weeklyCost,
    monthlyCost: monthlyCost
  };
}

document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var userCostOfGas = +document.forms[0].costOfGas.value;  // < Move these lines here and
  var userMPG = +document.forms[0].vehicleMPG.value;       // < add a plus sign before them
  var userNumMiles = +document.forms[0].numMiles.value;    // <
  var costs = calcCost(userCostOfGas, userMPG, userNumMiles);
  var calculatedMonthlyCost = document.getElementById("calculatedMonthlyCost");
  calculatedMonthlyCost.innerHTML = (costs.weeklyCost).toFixed(2);
};
```

```html
<form>
  Cost of Gas: <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 3.10" name="costOfGas"/>
  <br>
  Vehicle MPG: <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 30" name="vehicleMPG"/>
  <br>
  How many miles do you drive to work (one-way): <input type="text" placeholder="ex: 10" name="numMiles"/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br>
</form>

<div id="calculatedMonthlyCost"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You save the value of your inputs before the onsubmit method is called. This actually saves a blank value since the variables are set before the user inputs a value and it's not dynamic. The values need to be checked on submit.

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
  var userCostOfGas = parseInt(document.forms[0].costOfGas.value,10);
  var userMPG = parseInt(document.forms[0].vehicleMPG.value,10);
  var userNumMiles = parseInt(document.forms[0].numMiles.value,10);

  e.preventDefault();
  var costs = calcCost(userCostOfGas, userMPG, userNumMiles);
  var calculatedMonthlyCost = document.getElementById("calculatedMonthlyCost");
  calculatedMonthlyCost.innerHTML = costs.weeklyCost;
};
```